# Torsion subgroup of SO3 can not be dense

Tags: lie-groups

I've been trying to attack this problem in many ways, but Couldn't figure out the right answer .

The question is, That a finitely generated subgroup of SO3 when all the elements are of finite order, can not be dense .
This is a preceding question to proving that these subgroups are finite (so this statement is forbidden) .

It can be proven alternatively that this subgroup must be closed, but this is also a tough argument .

Answer (score 1):

The two questions also can be treated in a different order. We can first solve the second question. Indeed, all finitely generated torsion subgroups of $SO(3)$ are finite, see here:

[Finitely generated torsion subgroup of $SO(3,\mathbb{R})$ is finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2552822/finitely-generated-torsion-subgroup-of-so3-mathbbr-is-finite)

Hence such subgroups cannot be dense.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer .
Yes this is true, but it kinda loses the whole point of the ex., proving this independently of Schur's Theorem, out of topological (or other) properties

Comment: Do you have the whole text of this exercise? What are the basic results of the lecture before this exercise?

Comment: No primary results :
It is a classical theorem of I. Schur that a finitely generated
subgroup of GLn(C) all of whose elements are of finite order
(called a periodic, or torsion, group) is a finite group.
Challenge (). Prove, independently of Schur's theorem,
that a periodic subgroup of SO3(R) cannot be dense.

Comment: Then use Selberg's theorem. This is very elementary.